# Options for implementing search in php/mysql site

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

So I have a simple classified site in php/mysql , to which I need to add search capability. 
I can't use mysql FULLTEXT feature , as I require 3 character long words to be part of the index. What are my options ?

I am looking at zend search lucene . And while it would do the job, I am wondering if there is something better . Example: for implementing zend search lucene I would have to make 3 methods , one to add to the index when a post is created, one to delete from the index  when a post is deleted and finally one to create index from existing posts.

Is there something more automatic or should I just stick with lucene.

Thanks

Comment: you can use full text on any size character string, you just have to adjust the mysql settings.

Comment: but do I have an option of changing mysql settings on shared hosting ?

Comment: ask the host. dedicated hosting is not that expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Having used Zend_Search_Lucene in a rather big project I can say that it's not well suited for that. Small to medium sized projects should be fine, but if the data set is too large you'll run into problems with a pure PHP implementation of Lucene. Mostly that it becomes rather slow, since it can't keep things in memory, and that PHP will run out of memory for large result sets.

I'd recommend a standalone search server like Solr, which will give you more flexibility in the long run.